# Issues creating a new repository in github desktop from a duplicated project directory

Tags: github, github-desktop

I have duplicated a directory, renamed it and made changes to the files to suit the new project. The reason I duplicated the original directory was so that I could use it as a boilerplate and not have to setup the new project from scratch.

My understanding was that when you do this, you have a new directory and you can create a new repository in github desktop.

However I get:
[image]

Any suggestions as in how I could create a new repository for the new project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The duplicate is also a 'repository' because it has the `.git` file with it. Maybe you should just change the copy's remotes and you're good to go.

```
git remote remove <remote name>
git remite add <remote name> <remote link>
```